# Javascript Download Item from Dropdown

Tags: javascript, wordpress, download, advanced-custom-fields

Drop down, when item of dropdown is selected I need it to go to download page based on the advanced custom fields value.

Code:

```
<select name="download" onChange="download(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Select template to download</option>
    <option value="<?php the_field('download_template_1_link', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('download_template_1_title', 'option'); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php the_field('download_template_2_link', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('download_template_2_title', 'option'); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php the_field('download_template_3_link', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('download_template_3_title', 'option'); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php the_field('download_template_4_link', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('download_template_4_title', 'option'); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php the_field('download_template_5_link', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('download_template_5_title', 'option'); ?></option>


    <script>
        function download(val) {
            window.location 
        }
    </script>



</select>
```

Comment: What did you try ? Can you post more of the JS ?

Comment: That's all of it. My problem is I need to set window.location to the value that is selected in the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use window.location.href to go to download page.

```
<script>
    function download(val) {
        window.location.href = val;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function download(url) {
  if (url.length !== 0) {
    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

```html
<select onChange="download(this.value)">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="http://apple.com">Apple</option>
  <option value="http://bing.com">Bing</option>
</select>
```